# string to date conversion not working in .NET Core

Tags: c#, datetime

when i try to convert string to date following exception occured

```
FormatException: String '11/17/2020 3:23 PM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

my code is ...

```
public class PaperDTO
{
     ...
    [DeadLineValidate(maxday: 62, ErrorMessage = "please specify valid date maximum 62 days are valid")]
    public string DeadLine { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DeadLineValidate : ValidationAttribute
{
    public DeadLineValidate(int maxday){ Maxday = maxday; }

    public int Maxday { get; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var date = DateTime.ParseExact(value as string, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return DateTime.Today <= date && date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(Maxday);
    }
}
```

if i use in my action method...

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

then it works fine
but in this approach i have to change culture of thread just for date conversion and unnecessarily i have to write extra code in action method of controller

does anyone have any idea regarding this ?

Comment: If your input is a string, you should also validate the string representation format. Prefer `TryParseExact` over `ParseExact` to avoid the exception

Comment: don't understand why you need to change culture of thread for this. What error will you get if you ignore this ?

Comment: Looks like you should be using `h` rather than `hh`: `hh` expects the hour as 2 digits i.e. 01 - 12, whereas your string is simply `3`.

Comment: This error has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core or even .NET Core, in fact there are a *lot* of duplicate questions already. The string doesn't match the US format requested by using `InvariantCulture`. The fix is to *not* use strings in the first place.

Comment: @ZoharPeled now i am getting false my code is .. `if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value as string, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i have already gone threw those questions can you suggest any specific question via link ?

Comment: @JanakVaghasiya where did this string come from? All .NET/.NET Core date picker controls produce strongly-typed `DateTime` values and Javascript date pickers produce ISO8601 dates, which are converted to DateTime by MVC/Razor pages binders. You'll always have problems if you try to hard-code the US format

Comment: @JanakVaghasiya all those questions have been answered. You're still trying to do the wrong thing - work with a localized string literal. Avoid that completely. Either use `DateTime` or an ISO8601 string

Comment: @JanakVaghasiya this means that `Deadline` should be a `DateTime`, never a string. Using a `string` in the DTO is a bug to begin with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date pattern requires **2 digits** for the hour, but your value has only **1 digit**. Try this date pattern instead, it will support both 1 and 2 digits:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt"
```

Note that the same issue (and the same solution) might apply for the Month and Day values.